# -Ansi and comments giving errors?

Tags: c, comments, c89

I'm getting errors while compiling with `-ansi -pedantic` on lines that have `// Comment here`. Why does this happen?

> expected expression before '/' token
>
> stray '\347' in program

Example code `int someVariable = 0; // Some comment`

I have many many errors of these, what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C89 does not support C++-style comments.

Comment: To be completely pedantic, ANSI C *does* support C++-style comments, because the ANSI C standard is c99.  What many people and compilers incorrectly refer to as "ANSI C" (c89) does not.

Answer (score 4):

Because the gcc developers are mistaken about what `ANSI C` means, or kept the option aligned to an old standard for "compatibility". ANSI C is ISO C is C99, which allows `//` comments, but when many people say `ANSI C` they mean "the first standardization of the C language by ANSI", i.e. C89. The gcc `-ansi` option is equivalent to `-std=c89`.

If you're trying to enforce conformance to modern standards, you should use `-std=c99` instead of `-ansi`.

Comment: And file a bug against gcc while you're at it!

Comment: I gave up on that. My favorite bug-closure justification ever was: "In any case, just because code is syntactically 'valid' GNU C doesn't mean gcc can always compile it." :-)